# Linear Transformation Basis Exercise

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, coordinate-systems

I have tried to solve the following exercise. Is it right?

> Consider the [linear transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) L: ℝ⁴→ ℝ³. Knowing that:
>
> $$
> L \begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2\\2\\2\end{pmatrix}
> \space
> L \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}
> \space
> L \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}
> \space
> L \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}
> \space
> $$
>   Determine the image of the elements in the standard basis of ℝ⁴ through L.

---

$$
\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} + 0 \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} + 0 \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} + 0 \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}
\\
L \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} = L \left( \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} + 0 \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} + 0 \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} + 0 \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix} \right) = \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}2\\2\\2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}
$$

---

$$
\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} = -\frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} + 1 \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} + 0 \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} + 0 \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}
\\
L \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} = L \left( -\frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} + 1 \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} + 0 \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} + 0 \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix} \right) = -\frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}2\\2\\2\end{pmatrix} + 1 \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}
$$

---

$$
\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} = 0 \begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} - 1 \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} + 1 \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} + 0 \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}
\\
L \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} = L \left( 0 \begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} - 1 \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} + 1 \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} + 0 \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix} \right) = -1 \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} + 1 \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix}
$$

---

$$
\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix} = 0 \begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} + 0 \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} - 1 \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} + 1 \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}
\\
L \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix} = L \left( 0 \begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} + 0 \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} - 1 \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} + 1 \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix} \right) = - 1 \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} + 1 \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}
$$

---

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is right, but your method looks a bit convoluted. In these cases, one usually works with matrices that represent the transformation. First, determine the change of basis matrix $M_{\mathcal{S}_4,\mathcal{B}}$, where $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathbb{R}^4$ is the given basis and $\mathcal{S}_4 \subset \mathbb{R}^4$ is the standard basis. Then the linear transformation matrix is
$$
M_{\mathcal{S}_4,\mathcal{S}_3}(L) =
M_{\mathcal{B},\mathcal{S}_3}(L)
\cdot
M_{\mathcal{S}_4,\mathcal{B}}
$$
We know that $$M_{\mathcal{S}_4,\mathcal{B}}=M_{\mathcal{B},\mathcal{S}_4}^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
M_{\mathcal{B},\mathcal{S}_3}(L) =
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Where $\mathcal{S}_3$ is the standard basis in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Therefore,
$$
M_{\mathcal{S}_4,\mathcal{S}_3}(L) =
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The columns of $M_{\mathcal{S}_4,\mathcal{S}_3}$ are the images of the vectors of $\mathcal{S}_4$.